# How do I read this YAML?

Tags: go, yaml

I have a YAML configuration file like below

```
development: true
databases:
  - label: masterdata
    properties:
      host: localhost
      port: 54321
      user: admin
      password: nimda
      dialect: postgres
      dbname: business
  - label: transactional
    properties:
      host: localhost
      port: 54321
      user: webuser
      password: insecure
      dialect: postgres
      dbname: web
```

And structure like below

```
type ApplicationConfiguration struct {
    development bool         `yaml:"development"`
    databases   []Properties `yaml:"databases"`
}

type Properties struct {
    Label  string            `yaml:"label"`
    Values map[string]string `yaml:"properties"`
}
```

Using library `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`

Attempt to read this

```
config := ApplicationConfiguration{}
b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(configPath)
marshalError := yaml.Unmarshal(b, &config)
```

But the value of databases in `config` is always nil and development always false, which means it not being unmarshalled at all. How can I read this configuration, may be I am using wrong struct or yaml needs change or a different API?

Comment: This is because `development` and `databases` are private. the `yaml` package can only see public fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to unmarshel it using the following struct:

```
type ApplicationConfiguration struct {
Development bool `yaml:"development"`
Databases   []struct {
    Label      string `yaml:"label"`
    Properties struct {
        Host     string `yaml:"host"`
        Port     int    `yaml:"port"`
        User     string `yaml:"user"`
        Password string `yaml:"password"`
        Dialect  string `yaml:"dialect"`
        Dbname   string `yaml:"dbname"`
    } `yaml:"properties"`
} `yaml:"databases"`
```

if you need to unmarshal your props into map, try the followings:

1. using map[string]interface{}
   type Properties struct {
   Label  string            `yaml:"label"`
   Values map[string]interface{} `yaml:"properties"`
   }

marshal it into a struct and then using the following example:

```
type databases interface{}

 var myMap map[string]interface{}
```

2. using struct and process it after:

   ```
   if v.Kind() == reflect.Map {
   for _, key := range v.MapKeys() {
       strct := v.MapIndex(key)
       fmt.Println(key.Interface(), strct.Interface())
   }}
   ```

Comment: Just the change


type ApplicationConfiguration struct {
 Development bool         `yaml:"development"`
 Databases   []Properties `yaml:"databases"`
}

type Properties struct {
 Label  string            `yaml:"label"`
 Values map[string]string `yaml:"properties"`
}


Works